# How to add <span> between text and image?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have `some text` on the left, and an image on the right, now when device is mobile, a  needs to be added between this `some text` and the image. When the device is a PC, the  should be disabled.

I tried using : `<span style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-lg ellipsis">` but when the user is on mobile, the `some text` is present, then the  on the next like, and the image on another line. I want the image to look like up[image: I want the image to look like this]

But it is coming like :[image]

My code is as below:

```
<div class="divStyle" ng-click="showShipTo()" style=" margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 5px;" >
        <a class="placeOrder" style="margin-left: 15px;">
        Ship To
        </a>                
        <span style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-lg userDetails ellipsisOverflow">
            {{product.address.first_name+" "+product.address.last_name+", "}}
            {{product.address.street+", "}}
            {{product.address.city+" "+product.address.state+" "+product.address.zip_code}}
        </span>

        <img align="right" style="margin-top: 14px; margin-right: 14px; " 
        ng-src="modules/checkoutProcess/arrow.png" alt="Arrow Image" height="20" width="20">
```

Please can any one suggest any help...

Thanks

Comment: So is the `span` correctly showing only when on mobile? or is the problem that it is pushing the content onto a new line?

Comment: `span` is supposed to be shown only in the mobile. I'm using bootstrap to make it responsive.

Comment: Please add working fiddle, without Angular

Comment: You could use something like [this](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)?